# MongoDB update a field if the subdocument exists

Tags: c#, mongodb

I only find questions about the other way around. But in my case I need to update a subdocument *auditInfo* which might or might not exist. In case it does not exist, it should be ignored. But using the `$set` operator would create the field in this case.

If it does exist, then I'd like to update it using `$set` to update single fields of the subdocument.

So far I haven't found any solution to this. Moreover I'm using a combined update definition for the whole document, so this way it is not possible to execute another `updateOne` with a filter on the field. The only way would either be an operator that does it automatically or maybe some array filter magic (but since the subdocument is at the root of the document I guess array filters won't work here).

This is my document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6409b3bdaa5da4b2cecb2fda"
  },
  "Version": 1,
  "auditInfo": {
    "Version": 1,
    "creationTimestamp": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "-62135596800000"
      }
    },
    "changeTimestamp": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1678359412574"
      }
    },
    "creationUser": {
      "$binary": {
        "base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==",
        "subType": "04"
      }
    },
    "changeUser": {
      "$binary": {
        "base64": "KIvTths/Q1GsbEp1L04axA==",
        "subType": "04"
      }
    }
  },
  "dataFieldContainerId": {
    "$binary": {
      "base64": "RFv0FiWNQOi5Ei9ZBlU/OA==",
      "subType": "04"
    }
  },
  "dataFields": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

I need to update `changeTimestamp` and `changeUser` if the subdocument `auditInfo` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation between $cond and $exists.
check with a $cond statement if the auditInfo exists then execute your query.
you can find how to use it here :
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: Thanks, but I really hoped I could update the whole document in one call. I guess even with aggregations I need to separate the one with condition from the other updates which do only rely on array filters but don't have to check for existance.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can use [$exists](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) into `find` object to update only values where `auditInfo` exists.

So I think you are looking for [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iF728GU9C9T)

And can be translated into c# code into something like this (not tested):

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId("6409b3bdaa5da4b2cecb2fda")),
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("auditInfo")
);

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("auditInfo.changeTimestamp", DateTime.Now)
                                          .Set("auditInfo.changeUser", yourUser);

var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: And that's the pitfall I mentioned in my question. That's likely working, but since I generate a list of update definitions and use `Combine` on them, I am kinda forced to execute one single `updateOne` call. Thus I can only specify a filter that works for all (bascially just the `$eq: id`). The question is whether there's an operator for this, but looks like that's the one thing MongoDB sadly is lacking.